# How to expand all sections in Text Compare of Beyond Compare?

Tags: diff, code-folding, beyondcompare

I have a bunch of code differences in the `Text Compare` view of `Beyond Compare`... but they are easier to understand if the context of that block is expanded. I have many of these sections, and it's tedious to expand each one, especially because I've accidentally clicked the "move line" button which is very nearby. Isn't there an `Expand All` like Pycharm has for it's `code folding` right-click menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Beyond Compare's Text Compare, select **View | Show All** from the menu to display all lines.

To view differences with a few matching lines above and below each difference, select **View | Show Differences**, then turn on **View | Show Context**.

The above commands are also available as the **All**, **Diffs**, and **Context** toolbar buttons.